# Google App Maker not available on 16th March 2018

Tags: google-app-maker

On 16th March (Friday), we and our client (SPH Singapore) noticed that we couldn't access to https://appmaker.google.com/ from Chrome browser and it's impacted our works for a few hours. Please see the error as below:

"error: 404 not found (The requested URL / was not found on this server.)"

We have reported the issue to Google Cloud Support team, however they are not able to provide the outage report and what's the root cause for the issue since they are not involved in App Maker. They have suggested to contact your team here and post a question so that you can answer the questions.

We do appreciate if you can provide the outage report and the root cause for this issue.

Regards,
Ikhmal

Answer (score 0):

There was an accidental rollback of access for a set of EAP domains during a series of preparations for eventual GA. This has now been restored.
Let us know if your client sees any new issues.

Thanks and apologies for the hassle,
-Chris (Google App Maker)

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your update. Is it possible if we can get the rollback or outage report so that we can provide to our client?

Comment: Hi Chris... I just discovered AppMaker and seem to have missed the EAP. Can you give any hints as to when it might be available in GA? Or can you help me get on the EAP? Thanks